# Re-render logic for children of parent which updates muliple times per second

Tags: reactjs

So I have a component which the state is updated multiple times a second by a child element.

To prevent over-rendering i use the shouldComponentUpdate on the other children to make sure they don't re-render too much.

The element of the state that is updated is required by another child further down the tree.

I would only like that child element to rerender, and not the intermediary children, again, to avoid over-rendering.

How could one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would only like that child element to rerender, and not the intermediary children, again, to avoid over-rendering. How could one do that?

You can't via the traditional method of passing the state down as props. A change in state in the parent component cannot trigger a re-render on the grand-child component C without triggering a re-render on the child component B first.

For a component to update a child, it needs to go through its life-cycle before it can pass down new props to it.

To my knowledge, the only way around this is to use a state management library, such as Redux or MobX, or use the React Context API and move that state variable there and then "consume" it in your grand-child component.

That being said, unless your tree is multiple levels deep and you don't see any performance issues, I would consider keep using `shouldComponentUpdate()` like you are already doing.